# Drawing a (4x4)-grid in TikZ using `\foreach` - riding the wave of `\foreach` fun

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

How do I draw a `4x4` grid over the following `TikZ` diagram using `\foreach`? Is it preferable to do so with one `\foreach` command?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}



\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{minipage}{3.5in}
\noindent \raggedright{\textbf{1.) }The following figure is composed of quarter-arcs \\
of circles of radii 1, 2, 3, and 4. Calculate the area \\
enclosed by the polygon.}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{0.25cm}
%
\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]

\path[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] ({(3/4)*4},0) -- (0,0) arc (180:90:{(3/4)*4}) -- ({(3/4)*4},0) -- cycle;
\path[fill=white] ({(3/4)*4},{(3/4)*1}) -- ({(3/4)*1},{(3/4)*1}) arc (180:90:{(3/4)*3});
\path[fill=blue!50] ({(3/4)*3},{(3/4)*1}) -- ({(3/4)*1},{(3/4)*1}) arc (180:90:{(3/4)*2}) -- cycle;
\draw[blue] ({(3/4)*1},{(3/4)*1}) arc (180:90:{(3/4)*2});
\path[fill=white] ({(3/4)*3},{(3/4)*2}) -- ({(3/4)*2},{(3/4)*2}) arc (180:90:{(3/4)*1});
\draw[blue] ({(3/4)*2},{(3/4)*2}) arc (180:90:{(3/4)*1});
\path[fill=white] ({(3/4)*4},{(3/4)*2}) -- ({(3/4)*4},{(3/4)*0}) arc (270:180:{(3/4)*2});
\draw[blue] ({(3/4)*4},{(3/4)*0}) arc (270:180:{(3/4)*2});

%A 4 \times 4 lattice grid is drawn.
%\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3} {\draw ({(3/4)*\x},0) -- ({(3/4)*\x},{(3/4)*1});}
%\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3} {\draw (0,{(3/4)*\y}) -- ({(3/4)*1},{(3/4)*\y});}

\end{tikzpicture}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw (0,0) grid[step=3/4] (3,3);`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am trying to familiarize myself with the `\foreach` command.  May you furnish it?

Comment: Please keep your `grid`-command in the comments, though.

Comment: If you really want a `foreach` solution, you can try `\foreach\t in {0,.75,...,3}\draw (\t,0)--(\t,3) (0,\t)--(3,\t);`.

Comment: @Kpym  Is there any reason you used `\t` instead of `\x` or `\y`?

Comment: @Adelyn No reason, you can use any valid macro name : `\t`, `\x`,`\bingo`,... (even `~` is ok if you don't need unbreakable spaces inside the loop).

Comment: Also, \x0-\x2, \y0-\y2 and \p0-\p2 are used as pseudo-registers in TikZ.  There might be odd effects caused by redefining \x, \y or \p inside a foreach loop.

Comment: @Adelyn With`grid` you can use: `\draw[step=0.75] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);`

Comment: @Adelyn With `\foreach` you can use:
`\foreach \p in {0,0.75,...,3} {\draw(\p,0)--(\p,3) (0,\p)--(3,\p);}`
adapted from [pgfmanual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) pag. 903.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.